# Using pointers to numpy array data attribute

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to solve the bottleneck in my application, which is an elementwise sum of two matrices.

I'm using NumPy and Cython. I have a `cdef` class with a matrix attribute. Since Cython still doesn't support buffer arrays in class attributes, I followed [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cython-users/vFXntLy_s9Q) and tried to use a pointer to the `data` attribute of the matrix. The thing is, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, as the results indicate.

What I tried to do is more or less the following:

```
cdef class the_class:
    cdef np.ndarray the_matrix
    cdef float_t* the_matrix_p

    def __init__(self):
        the_matrix_p = <float_t*> self.the_matrix.data

    cpdef the_function(self):
        other_matrix = self.get_other_matrix()


        the_matrix_p += other_matrix.data
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have serious doubt that adding two numpy arrays is a bottleneck that you can solve rewriting things in C. See the follwing code, that uses [`scipy.weave`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/weave.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.weave import inline

a = np.random.rand(10000000)
b = np.random.rand(10000000)
c = np.empty((10000000,))

def c_sum(a, b, c) :
    length = a.shape[0]
    code = '''
           for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
           {
               c[j] = a[j] + b[j];
           }
           '''
    inline(code, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'length'])
```

Once you run `c_sum(a, b, c)` once to get the C code compiled, these are the timings I get:

```
In [12]: %timeit c_sum(a, b, c)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.5 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit np.add(a, b, out=c)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.6 ms per loop
```

So it seems you are looking at something of a .3% performance improvement, if the timing differences are not simply random noise, on an operation that takes a handful of ms when working on arrays of ten million elements. If it really is a bottleneck, this is hardly going to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. After a couple of measurements, I came to the conclusion that my code is as fast as it can be in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling ATLAS and recompiling numpy after that. This won't probably help with addition, but you can have really nice performance boost with more complicated matrix operations (if you use such, of course).

Check out this [simple benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645872/1113562). If your results fall too far from those given in the post, maybe your numpy is not linked against some optimized BLAS implementation.