# libblas.so cannot open share project file in python?

Tags: python, numpy, lapack, blas

I'm a complete newbie with regards to this so please excuse my ignorance.

I wanted to run the benchmark from this question:

[Benchmarking (python vs. c++ using BLAS) and (numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596612/benchmarking-python-vs-c-using-blas-and-numpy)

The code can be found here:
https://github.com/zed/woltan-benchmark/

after running `make` I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    _blaslib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libblas.so")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [Test.csv] Error 1
```

I'm guessing that it can't find the `libblas.so` library, but no idea where it is? How can I check if it's installed? I'm running Ubuntu 13.10.

Thanks you

ADDITIONAL INFO:

The python code triggering the error found in `main.py` is:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import byref, c_char, c_int, c_float
import numpy
import os
import subprocess
import timeit

_blaslib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libblas.so")

def Mul(m1, m2, i, r):

    no_trans = c_char("n")
    n = c_int(i)
    one = c_float(1.0)
    zero = c_float(0.0)

    _blaslib.sgemm_(byref(no_trans), byref(no_trans), byref(n), byref(n), byref(n), byref(one), m1.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), byref(n), 
                                                                                                m2.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), byref(n), byref(zero),
                                                                                                r.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), byref(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    rNumpy = []
    rBlas = []

    p = subprocess.Popen("./bench {0}".format(str([x for x in range(5, 501, 5)])[1:-1]), shell = True)
    os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)

    for i in range(20, 501, 20):
        m1 = numpy.random.rand(i,i).astype(numpy.float32)
        m2 = numpy.random.rand(i,i).astype(numpy.float32)

        tNumpy = timeit.Timer("numpy.dot(m1, m2)", "import numpy; from __main__ import m1, m2")
        rNumpy.append((i, tNumpy.repeat(20, 1)))

        r = numpy.zeros((i,i), numpy.float32)
        tBlas = timeit.Timer("Mul(m1, m2, i, r)", "import numpy; from __main__ import i, m1, m2, r, Mul")
        rBlas.append((i, tBlas.repeat(20, 1)))
        print i

    f = open("Test.csv", "w")

    for (i, n), (j, b) in zip(rNumpy, rBlas):
        f.write("{0} {1} {2} {3} ".format(i, sum(n)/len(n), min(n), max(n)))
        f.write("{0} {1} {2} {3}\n".format(j, sum(b)/len(b), min(b), max(b)))

    f.close()
```

EDIT 1:

After running `locate libblas.so` I replaced

```
_blaslib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libblas.so")
```

with

```
_blaslib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/usr/lib/libblas/libblas/libblas.so.3")
```

not sure if this is correct but it now the output looks like:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Under linux, you use the locate command, ie: locate libblas.so

Comment: One more thing, it looks like you may not have BLAS installed. Do *apt-cache search libblas*

Comment: thanks for that. I got a number of them eg `/usr/lib/libblas.so.3`, `/usr/lib/libblas.so.3.0`

Comment: is there something specific you want me to output from the `apt-cache search` command, it gave me a very long list of things... of which some are `libblas-dev`, `libopenblas-base`

Comment: Make sure the path is in your loader search path.

Answer (score 0):

Both errors (`OSError` and "core dumped") are due to `libblas.so` is not found in `main.py` and `main.cpp` correspondingly and it seems `libblas.so.3` should be used in your case.

I've updated [the benchmark](https://github.com/zed/woltan-benchmark/) to make `libblas.so` name configurable.

On my system (Ubuntu 14.04) both:

```
$ make clean && make
```

and

```
$ make clean && make LIBBLAS_SO=libblas.so.3
```

work.

```sh
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libblas.so
... /usr/lib/libblas.so -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so
```

```sh
$ update-alternatives --display libblas.so
libblas.so - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so
/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so - priority 10
  slave libblas.a: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.a
/usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so - priority 40
  slave libblas.a: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.a
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so'.
```