# Why MATLAB/Numpy/Scipy performance is slow and doesn't reach CPU capabilities (flops)?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, scipy

First of all, I know there are multiple threads that touch this issue, however I could not get a straight answer and encountered some flops miscalculations.

I have prepared a MATLAB and Python benchmark of element-wise multiplication. This is the simplest and most forward way one can easily calculate the flop count.

It uses NxN array (matrix) but does not do a matrix multiplication, rather an element wise multiplication. This is important because when using the matrix multiplication the number of operation is not N^3 !!!

The [lower level algorithm that performs matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm) does it in less than N^3 operations.

The execution of element-wise multiplication of randomly generated numbers however, will have to be performed in N^2 operations

I have an intel i7-4770 (which I think have 4 physical cores and 8 virtual cores) @ 3.5GHz. So if assuming 4flops per cycle that should be 14 GFLOPS per core!

MATLAB/Numpy/Scipy don't get anywhere near.

Why?

MATLAB:

```
%element wise multiplication benchmark
N = 10^4;
nOps = N^2;
m1 = randn(N);
m2 = randn(size(m1));
m = randn(size(m1));

m1 = single(m1);
m2 = single(m2);

% clear m
tic
m1 = m1 .* m2;
t = toc;
gflops = nOps/t*1e-9;
t_gflops = [t gflops]

% clear m
tic
m1 = m1.*m2;
t = toc;
gflops = nOps/t*1e-9;
t_gflops = [t gflops]


% clear m
tic
m1 = m1.*m2;
t = toc;
gflops = nOps/t*1e-9;
t_gflops = [t gflops]

version('-blas')
version('-lapack')
```

Which results in:

```
t_gflops =

    0.0978    1.0226


t_gflops =

    0.0743    1.3458


t_gflops =

    0.0731    1.3682


ans =

Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.1.1 Product Build 20131010 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications



ans =

Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.1.1 Product Build 20131010 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
Linear Algebra PACKage Version 3.4.1
```

And now Python:

```
import numpy as np
# import gnumpy as gnp
import scipy as sp
import scipy.linalg as la
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 10**4
    nOps = N**2
    a = np.random.randn(N,N).astype(np.float32)
    b = np.random.randn(N,N).astype(np.float32)

    t = time.time()
    c = a*b
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    t = time.time()
    c = np.multiply(a, b)
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    t = time.time()
    c = sp.multiply(a, b)
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    t = time.time()
    c = sp.multiply(a, b)
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    a = np.random.randn(N,1).astype(np.float32)
    b = np.random.randn(1,N).astype(np.float32)

    t = time.time()
    c1 = np.dot(a, b)
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    t = time.time()
    c = np.dot(a, b)
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    t = time.time()
    c = la.blas.dgemm(1.0,a,b)
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    t = time.time()
    c = la._fblas.dgemm(1.0,a,b)
    dt = time.time()-t
    gflops = nOps/dt*1e-9
    print("dt = ", dt, ", gflops = ", gflops)

    print("numpy config")
    np.show_config()
    print("scipy config")
    sp.show_config()
    # numpy
```

Which result in:

```
dt =  0.16301608085632324 , gflops =  0.6134364136022663
dt =  0.16701674461364746 , gflops =  0.5987423610209003
dt =  0.1770176887512207 , gflops =  0.5649152957845881
dt =  0.188018798828125 , gflops =  0.5318617107612401
dt =  0.151015043258667 , gflops =  0.6621856858903415
dt =  0.17201733589172363 , gflops =  0.5813367558659613
dt =  0.3080308437347412 , gflops =  0.3246428142959423
dt =  0.39503931999206543 , gflops =  0.253139358385916
```

numpy config

mkl_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include']
```

lapack_mkl_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include']
```

lapack_opt_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include']
```

blas_opt_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include']
```

openblas_lapack_info:

NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include']
```

scipy config

mkl_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
```

lapack_mkl_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
```

lapack_opt_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
```

blas_opt_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
```

openblas_lapack_info:

NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:

```
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
library_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
include_dirs = ['C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\include', 'C:\\Minonda\\envs\\_build\\Library\\lib']
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Comparing against theoretical limits of your CPU is rarely helpful because you'll never be able to squeeze that sort of power out of your processor (among other things, it's busy with other things...).  It might be more illuminating to time some equivalent C code to multiply a couple of arrays and see how python/matlab perform compared to _that_.

Comment: Did you try your luck with GPU processing?

Comment: C code should invoke BLASS
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596612/benchmarking-python-vs-c-using-blas-and-numpy

The originator of the above thread seemed to succeed in doing so, however the guys who repeated his benchmark couldn'y (I don't have a linux so it was to painful to try on my PC)

Comment: Regarding GPU - i tried doing gnumpy, but stumbled with some problems running it.

I found this however:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/10/06/experience-cudamat-deep-belief-networks-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in this case you're being limited by memory bandwidth, not CPU power. Assuming:

- [PC3-12800
  RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#JEDEC_standard_modules)
  in dual channel mode;
- for every multiplication (single precision) 12 bytes need to be transferred between CPU and RAM;

The theoretical maximum sustained performance would be about 2 GFLOPS. I calculated this number as `peak DDR3 transfer rate` * `number of RAM channels` / `bytes tranferred per FLOP`.

BTW, in numpy elementwise operations are not accelerated by BLAS. I'm not sure about MATAB.

Comment: This seems odd as there should be a cache. What is the cache size then ? if this is true then we should be able to fit the array size to the cache size and repeat the operation several time to get consistent flop count

Comment: @frishcor - The total size of arrays (`c = a .* b`) is 1.2 GB, but the i7-4770 largest cache is only 8 MB. Yes the measured FLOPS should increase if the array fits the cache, but even the L3 cache may be just a little to slow to top out the CPU, [see this graph](http://techreport.com/r.x/skylake/sandra-bw.gif).

Comment: I've tested it with loops over samller arrays - indeed there's improvement, though still get to only about 3GFLOPS. But I have to agree that this is a memory bound operation. Thx!